# how to use pan tool in papaya viewer

Tags: javascript, papaya

Hi there I have tried to implement PAN Tool for papaya viewer but no luck, I came up with these two functions

`papaya.viewer.Viewer.prototype.setCurrentPanLocation = function (xLoc, yLoc, sliceDirection) {`

and 
`papaya.viewer.Viewer.prototype.setStartPanLocation = function (xLoc, yLoc, sliceDirection) {`

anyone help

Comment: Alt-Shift-Drag -- have a look at the Wiki: https://github.com/rii-mango/Papaya/wiki/User-Interface-Features#mouse-controls

Comment: yes I have looked it but I want to make it pan at zoom = 1

Comment: Look in `setCurrentPanLocation()`.  The first line is `if (this.zoomFactor > 1) {`.  I would start there.  Also do a search for "zoomFactor > 1" -- it shows up in a few places.

Comment: Yes I got it thanks for the help bro..

Comment: Post it as answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After researching much detailed finally find this answer

```js
this.previousMousePosition.x = papaya.utilities.PlatformUtils.getMousePositionX(me);
this.previousMousePosition.y = papaya.utilities.PlatformUtils.getMousePositionY(me);
                    //  this.setStartPanLocationNew(Cord1.x, Cord1.y, this.mainImage.sliceDirection);
                    
this.setStartPanLocationNew(
                        this.convertScreenToImageCoordinateX(this.previousMousePosition.x, this.mainImage),
                        this.convertScreenToImageCoordinateY(this.previousMousePosition.y, this.mainImage),
                        this.mainImage.sliceDirection
                    );
```